# Two models each having a ManyToMany field referencing each other

Tags: django, django-models

I want males to have a ManytoMany field to female and same with male. The problem arises here that you can only reference models created before the model you are referencing them in:

```
class Male(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=300)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    d_O_b = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=300)
    #swipes = models.ManyToManyField(Females)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Female(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=300)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    d_O_b = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=300)
    swipes = models.ManyToManyField(Male)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Male(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'Male'
    swipes = models.ManyToManyField(Female)
```

Comment: You only need the M2M on one of the models. If you were to comment out `swipes` on model `Femaie` and uncomment the one on `Male` it would work. Alternatively, you could move your code for `Female` above `Male` so it is declared first and it will work without changing field declarations.

Comment: See my answer below for the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the name of the model rather than the model itself (called a "lazy relationship"):

```
class Male(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=300)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    d_O_b = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=300)
    swipes = models.ManyToManyField('Female', related_name="female_swipes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Female(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=300)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    d_O_b = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=300)
    swipes = models.ManyToManyField(Male, related_name="male_swipes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#lazy-relationships